# How to use perfect in this sentence

Tags: grammar, usage, standard-german, perfect-tense

I have a problem understanding how to use perfect in the following sentence:

> Ich bin mit dem Bus in das Stadtzentrum gefahren.

I know we are supposed to use the auxiliary verb **haben** in perfect when we have an **accusative object** in the sentence.

Does this apply when there is an **accusative object** as a **local preposition**?

Comment: Es gibt die Hilfsverben "haben" und "sein". Mit dem Bus hat man nicht, sondern ist ins Stadtzentrum gefahren. Man hat es vielleicht erreicht. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An accusative *phrase* that is part of a prepositional phrase is **not** an accusative *object*.

*Fahren* has no accusative object here, just an attribute to indicate direction. Therefore, its correct perfect auxiliary is indeed "sein", as in

> Ich **bin** in die Stadt gefahren.

It would be a different case if you added a real accusative object to it:

> Ich **habe meinen Sohn** in die Stadt gefahren.
>   (I drove my son to town.)